# Removing an animation in a sublayer

Tags: swift

I am creating a pulsating animation and adding it as a sublayer of an imageView. After an action I need to remove the animation but am struggling to find out how to.

This is when the layer gets created

```swift
func addPulse() {
        let pulse = Pulsing(numberOfPulses: Float.infinity, radius: 140, position: imageView.center)

        pulse.animationDuration = 0.8
        pulse.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.8549019694, green: 0.250980407, blue: 0.4784313738, alpha: 1)

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(pulse, below: imageView.layer)
    }
```

In order to remove it I use the following code which however crashed my application

```swift
self.imageView.layer.sublayers = []
```

I tried looking on stackOverflow and this is the solution they suggest but it doesn't work for me, do you suggest something?

Comment: doesn't work... it doesnt end the animation

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
self.imageView.layer.sublayers?.forEach {
    if $0 is Pulsing {
        $0.removeFromSuperlayer()  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried something like this:

```
for (CALayer *layer in self.view.layer.sublayers) {
    [layer removeFromSuperlayer];
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much an `objc` duplicate of @Sh_Khan's answer (less the `is Pulsing` check)?